# How to update links and coerce multiple parents in d3.cluster?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

d3 newbie here, so apologies in advance if anything doesn't make sense/is extremely silly.

I currently have a phylogenic tree in a collapsible cluster layout and am trying to solve the problem of multiple parents. I don't have enough points to post an image, so [here's the screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGmU6.png).

In the screengrab, the orphaned nodes (Moustached Grass Warbler, etc.) on the left moved from the links on the right that no longer have a node attached. I'd like these links to redraw, and connect the orphan nodes to its second parent (15601, 15602, etc.) Currently, the node moves to its new position but neither link is drawn.

I have since discovered that the hierarchical layouts aren't meant to work with nodes with multiple parents, but I don't yet understand d3 well enough to figure out why. Is there a way to get around this? I've become rather attached to the way that the cluster layout visualizes the data, so I'd really rather keep it, instead of starting over with a force layout as described [here](http://bl.ocks.org/GerHobbelt/3683278).

**So, my question: Is drawing two parent links to one node possible in d3.cluster? It really seems like it should be.  If so, how?**

If not, any more resources for how to duplicate the cluster layout in force would be much appreciated.

Here's the update function - let me know if more parts of the code are necessary:

```
function update(source) {
    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root);
        links = tree.links(nodes);

    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        add_parents(d);
    });

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) { 
        if (d.child_count === 0) {
                d.y = h - 150
        } else {
            //do nothing
        }
    });

  // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
        //this APPEARS to just cause it to update twice for no reason
        .on("click", function(d) { toggle(d); update(root); });

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", node_size)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return (d.child_count > 0 && d._children) ? "#66cccc" : "#fff"; });

  //switch out commented stuff in here for vertical vs horizontal tree
    nodeEnter.append("text")
        //.attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
        //.attr("dy", ".35em")
        //.attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
        .attr("dy", ".5em")
        .attr("dx", function(d) { return ( (node_size(d)/16 + (d.name.length/4) + 1) + "em"); })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(45)")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
        .attr("r", node_size)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return (d.child_count > 0 && d._children) ? "#66cccc" : "#fff"; });

    nodeUpdate.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
        .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6);

    nodeExit.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
        //this one prevents new link from being drawn to moved node, but links enter from the right place
        .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .style("stroke-opacity", link_opacity)
        //.style("stroke-width", link_width)
        .style("stroke", link_color)
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
        })
        .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });

} // function update()
```

Comment: make your question as short and concise as possible. It makes readers life easy.